# Objective-C NSString malloc error

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've got a method that creates a string then appends additional strings onto it:

```
-(NSString*)returnDetails {
    NSString *details = [[NSString alloc] init];

    details = [details stringByAppendingString:url];
    details = [details stringByAppendingString:@" : "];
    details = [details stringByAppendingString:author];

    return [details autorelease]; 
}
```

And I'm getting this error:

> iphoneapp_1(66508,0xacd9e2c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x6b9eb80: pointer being freed      was not allocated

If I change it to

```
NSString *details = [NSString string];
```

and remove the autorelease call, then it works. I would just like to understand why this works and my original method didn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NSString`'s method `stringByAppendingString:` returns an object that is already autoreleased. So returning `[details autorelease]` from your method will make that object will be released one more time than it must. Just return `details` instead.

You also have a memory leak in there, because you never released the string you allocated at the top of the method. Try this code :

```
-(NSString*)returnDetails {
    NSString *details = [NSString string];
    details = [details stringByAppendingString:url];
    details = [details stringByAppendingString:@" : "];
    details = [details stringByAppendingString:author];

    return details;
```

}

Answer (score 3):

When you call

```
details = [details stringByAppendingString:NSString*];
```

you create a new object that is already marked as autorelease. To achieve what you want, you could simply do:

```
-(NSString*)returnDetails {
  NSMutableString *details = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

  [details appendString:url];
  [details appendString:@" : "];
  [details appendString:author];

  return [details autorelease]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`stringByAppendingString:` gives you a string you do not own.  You must not release or autorelease it.

Your original, empty string leaks by the way.  You could just use:

```
NSString *details = @"";

details = [details stringByAppendingString:url];
details = [details stringByAppendingString:@" : "];
details = [details stringByAppendingString:author];

return details.
```

or

```
NSString details = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ : %@", url, author];
return details;
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are allocating and initializing NSString object and override that address later (mem-leak).

```
NSString *details = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

Later by calling stringByAppendingString you are getting already "autoreleased" object. Explicit autorelease is not redundant. It's double release.

Answer (score 1):

```
//This line

     NSString *details = [[NSString alloc] init];
    // In this you are allocating memory for the NSSTring object detail.

    in the very next lines:

    details = [details stringByAppendingString:url];
    details = [details stringByAppendingString:@" : "];
    details = [details stringByAppendingString:author];

    // Here you are making same object as autoreleased. That means you have make this instance free to release.

    Now in next line:

    return [details autorelease];

    // here you are autoreleasing the object which was already autoreleased. So it got crashed.
```

what you do is what @delannoyk user has advised:

```
{
 NSMutableString *details = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

  [details appendString:url];
  [details appendString:@" : "];
  [details appendString:author];

  return [details autorelease]; 
}
```